# Docomposition/transformation other than fourier transformation.

Tags: functional-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform, transformation, integral-transforms

It has been known that Fourier transformation is a very useful tool since it transform a variable from its form $x$ to a correlated basis.

However, is there any other decomposition or transformation method that can transform variables and functions into other basis, and what's their advantage and disadvantage compared to Fourier transformation? (for example, it seems to me that Laplace transformation can be used to solve partial differential equations, but why it is so rarely used in daily occasions?)

Comment: $\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st}dt$ is the Fourier transform of $f(t) e^{-\sigma t} 1_{t > 0}$. The main reason why we look at it for every $\sigma$ (instead of only one) is the analytic continuation and the tools from complex analysis. Do you know the orthogonal polynomials ? Some generalizations : the spectral theorem for compact operators in Hilbert spaces, providing an orthogonal basis where the operator acts diagonally, the diagonalization of the Laplacian in smooth manifolds, the representation theory in topological groups.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform#Table_of_transforms